# How to put data from array into label Swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift3, label

Im really new to Swift, the question is how can I represent values from array in label.

I want a TableView with cells dynamically represent values from array into the labels which will be created in tableView rows.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation



    class TableViewMarketItemsViewCell: UITableViewController {


        var fruits = ["Avocado", "Apricot", "Pomegranate", "Quince"]
        var PriceArray = ["1000 тг.","4000 тг.","3000 тг.","2000 тг."]
        var categoryArray = ["Green category","Maroon category","Red category","Yellow category"]

        // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return fruits.count
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

           let fruitName = fruits[indexPath.row]


            cell.productTitle.text = fruitName
            cell.productImage.image = UIImage(named: fruitName)



            return cell
        }


        }
```

Thnx in advance

Comment: https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

Comment: What have you tried already? What tutorials did you go through, what didn't work or what did you not understand? Show some code.

Answer (score 1):

```
import UIKit
import Foundation



    class TableViewMarketItemsViewCell: UITableViewController {


        var fruits = ["Avocado", "Apricot", "Pomegranate", "Quince"]
        var PriceArray = ["1000 тг.","4000 тг.","3000 тг.","2000 тг."]
        var categoryArray = ["Green category","Maroon category","Red category","Yellow category"]

        // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

        override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return fruits.count
        }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

           let fruitName = fruits[indexPath.row]


            cell.productTitle.text = fruitName
            cell.productImage.image = UIImage(named: fruitName)
            cell.productPrice.text = PriceArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.productsubTitle.text = categoryArray[indexPath.row]


            return cell
        }



        }
```

This helped me.

result in picture below:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7MWi.png)

Answer (score 1):

For inserting data into UITableViewcell use below code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var dataArray:NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        dataArray = NSArray(objects: "a","b","c")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray.object(at: indexPath.row) as? String
        return cell
    }

}
```

**tableView** is outlet of UItableView.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate an `UITableView` from an array like below:
(assuming that your array has a list of string values):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Creating the tableView cell
    let tableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    //Assigning values
    tableViewCell.lblName?.text = array.object(at: indexPath.row) as? String

    return tableViewCell
}
```

In this way you can show the value from your `array` to the `label` in your `tableView`.

Comment: *assuming that your array has a list of string values* in Swift it's `array[indexPath.row]`, no type cast, no optionals, `no object(at:`

Comment: @vadian: I didn't get you sir.

Comment: An array of strings is `[String]()`, the type is distinct and non-optional. So the type cast to optional (`as? String`) is nonsensical.